# \eqref{eq:..} doesn't work as expected

Tags: cross-referencing, equations

If I write something like this `As shown in \eqref{eq:..}` I would expect the following output after compilation:
"As shown in (1)".
However, I always get this:"As shown in equation (1)".

How can I prevent that the word "equation" is added?

I used the follwing documentclass:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Dokumentklasse UVKABook für A5%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{UVKABoA5}

\DeclareOption{twoside}{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrbook}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrbook}}
\DeclareOption{liststotocnumbered}{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrbook}}
\DeclareOption{idxtotoc}{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrbook}}
\DeclareOption{bibtotocnumbered}{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrbook}}
\DeclareOption{idxtotocnumbered}{
    \AtEndOfClass{
            \renewcommand*\idx@heading{
                    \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \twocolumn[\chapter{\indexname}]
                    \@mkboth{\indexname}{\indexname}
            }
    }
} \DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrbook}}
\ExecuteOptions{twoside,13pt,liststotocnumbered,idxtotocnumbered,bibtotocnumbered}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{scrbook}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\let\switcht@@therlang\relax
\let\svlanginfo\relax
\def\ds@deutsch{\def\switcht@@therlang{\switcht@deutsch}
\gdef\svlanginfo{\typeout{Deutsche Sprache}\global\let\svlanginfo\relax}}

\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{babel}{
\@ifundefined{extrasgerman}{}{\addto\extrasgerman{\switcht@deutsch}}
\@ifundefined{extrasngerman}{}{\addto\extrasngerman{\switcht@deutsch}}
}{\switcht@@therlang}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[titles]{tocloft}
\RequirePackage{makeidx}
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}
%\RequirePackage{natbib}
\RequirePackage{cite}            
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{scrpage2}
\RequirePackage[inner=3cm,%
                                                            outer=2cm,%
                                                            top=2.7cm,%
                                                            bottom=3.2cm]{geometry}
\clubpenalty = 10000
\widowpenalty = 10000
\displaywidowpenalty = 10000

%\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
%\bibliographystyle{straub}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}      

\setheadsepline{.4pt}

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{15}{15}\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{section}{\fontfamily{phv}\normalsize\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\fontfamily{phv}\normalsize\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\fontfamily{phv}\normalsize\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{caption}{\small}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\small}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\small}

\color[cmyk]{0,0,0,1}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\deffootnote[1.5em]{2em}{1.5em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}

\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\fontfamily{phv}\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\fontfamily{phv}\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\fontfamily{phv}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\fontfamily{phv}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\fontfamily{phv}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\fontfamily{phv}}

\newcommand{\preface}[1][\prefacename]{\chapter*{#1}}
\newcommand{\Preface}[1][\prefacename]{\chapter*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}

\newcommand{\ack}[1][\ackname]{\chapter*{#1}}
\newcommand{\Ack}[1][\ackname]{\chapter*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}

\newcommand{\abstract}[1][\abstractname]{\chapter*{#1}}
\newcommand{\Abstract}[1][\abstractname]{\chapter*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}

\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{\fontfamily{#1} \fontseries{#2} \fontshape{#3} \selectfont}

\def\ackname{Acknowledgment}
\def\abstractname{Abstract}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}
\def\switcht@deutsch{\svlanginfo
    \def\ackname{Danksagung}
    \def\abstractname{Kurzfassung}
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}
  \renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}
}

\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.33}
```

And at the beginning of my document I include the following:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}                                % Standartpaket zur Grafikeinbindung
\usepackage{amsmath}                                 % Erweiterung des Mathematik-Modus
\usepackage{amssymb}                                                 % Erweiterung des Mathematik-Modus
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                         % Neue, deutsche Rechtschreibung und Silbentrennung. 
\usepackage[english]{babel}                          % Englische Rechtschreibung und Silbentrennung.
\usepackage{supertabular}                            % Erweitere Tabellen
\usepackage{units}                                   % Einheiten in Formeln
\usepackage[thinspace,thinqspace,squaren]{SIunits}   % Vordefinierte SI-Einheiten
\usepackage{url}                                     % URLs formatieren
\usepackage{cite}                                    % Formatierung von Zitaten
\usepackage{pdfsync}                                           % PDF-Synchronisierung mit SumatraPDF
\usepackage{makeidx}                                               % Um einen Index zu erzeugen => z.B. mit GMTI\index{GMTI}
\usepackage{booktabs}                                % Für schönere Tabellenlinien
\usepackage{enumitem}                                % Anpassbare Enumerates/Itemizes
    \usepackage{multirow}                                                                % Zeilen/Spalten von Tabellen zusammenfassen
%\usepackage{trfsigns}                               % Zeichen für Transformationen

%\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}

\makeatletter
%\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces [#1]\unskip\@@italiccorr}}   % Anpassung der Formelnummerierung
\makeatother

\makeindex
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` and without a whole bunch of packages that quite surely will not affect your problem.

Comment: Further to Benedikt's comment, the example should be *minimal* and should compile without any further edits

Comment: According to point 3.11.2 of the `amsmath` [documentation](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) `\eqref` just adds "parentheses around the equation number". Which works fine for me if I try it with any example

Comment: By looking for an example I just found the error: There was a file included in my document template: `\include{content/commands}`. In this file the `\eqref`command was changed by `\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{equation~(\ref{#1})}`. My homemade problem is solved!

Comment: Congratulations, you just experienced the self-learning effect of building a MWE. Sorry if this sounds a bit ironic now but if have done this repeatedly you will find out that trying to reduce your Problem to a MWE will often make you find the problem yourself. And even if not it will in many cases enable you to ask a much more precise question then.